# Same print CSS as screen

Tags: css, printing, zurb-foundation

It seems like there should really be an easy solution to this, but so far I've been unsuccessful in finding one.

I'm using Zurb Foundation and I'm basically creating a live form that takes inputs from a form (above), and fills in a content (below) using angular.js.  Users will then print the page to a PDF.  I'd like to maintain the layout I have for the content below, and I'd like to hide the form above when printing.  Zurb has a fine "hide-for-print" css rule that seems like it should work just fine when applied to the form above, but when I toggle print stylesheets, it basically strips all CSS and goes back to ugly.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using CSS media queries for `print` media?

```
.foo {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:#F00  // see what I did there?
}

.bar {
    height:10px;
    width:50%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#000
}

.baz {
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

@media screen {
    .baz {
        display:block;
    }
}

@media print {
    .baz {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Now, only some of `.baz`'s properties are targeted by the media queries. You can feel free to put in any of `.baz`'s properties inside or outside of the queries themselves. Likewise, you can put *all* of `.baz`'s properties in the media query, but I gather that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: I understand the media queries, but the point is that I'm trying to have the _same_ styles for both, and simply hide something when printed. Copying all of my CSS into the print rule seems cumbersome.

Comment: What's stopping you? Put all styles besides the class/id in question outside the media query, and just have the media query apply for this rule. I'll update my answer to better illustrate my point.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in these type situations is use a separate file for the `print.css`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

If the browser is printing, the `global.css` file will be loaded first and than the `print.css` file will overwrite anything aftewards.

Keep in mind though, that all `background:  *` rules will be turned off in all browsers by default when printing, so some styles are going to be compromised regardless.

Answer (score 0):

idk about zurb's print style sheets, and without an example, it's pretty hard to answer, but you can use weasyprint, open source library to convert html/css to pdf https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint

Comment: This looks interesting, but where this seems to handle pagination very well, I'm looking for a simple one page document.

Comment: man my bad, i totally misread that. do what @phil says. just put display:none on your form in the print stylesheet.